# numeric variables showing categorical properties using statsmodels.api.ols

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, least-squares, statsmodels

I am using Python `statsmodels` module, and doing ANOVA on a linear model.
   The data source is http://www.scipy-lectures.org/_downloads/brain_size.csv.
   There are `40` samples, and the data has features: `Gender`, `FSIQ`, `VIQ`, `PIQ`, `Weight`, `Height` and `MRI_Count`. `Gender` is a categorical variable; `VIQ`, `PIQ` and `Weight` are numeric variables.

First if I assume the OLS regression model is `VIQ ~ C(Gender)+ PIQ`:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
model = ols('VIQ ~ C(Gender)+ PIQ', data).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

the outcomes shows:

```
                        coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
Intercept            19.4391     12.291      1.582      0.122        -5.466    44.344
C(Gender)[T.Male]     4.8628      4.751      1.024      0.313        -4.763    14.488
PIQ                   0.8149      0.107      7.613      0.000         0.598     1.032
```

So we see the coef of `PIQ` is 0.8149 and one can reject the null hypothesis that the coefficient of `PIQ = 0` (P-value is 0.000). But when I consider the other model: `VIQ ~ C(Gender) + Weight`,

```
model = ols('VIQ ~ C(Gender)+ Weight', data).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

Python regards `Weight` as categorical-like variable:

```
                        coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
Intercept            95.5000     25.365      3.765      0.009        33.434   157.566
C(Gender)[T.Male]    21.0000     20.710      1.014      0.350       -29.676    71.676
Weight[T.106]       -12.5000     32.746     -0.382      0.716       -92.626    67.626
Weight[T.114]        -9.5000     32.746     -0.290      0.781       -89.626    70.626
Weight[T.118]        35.0000     29.289      1.195      0.277       -36.667   106.667
Weight[T.122]        33.5000     32.746      1.023      0.346       -46.626   113.626
...
```

This is not what I want, since it interprets `VIQ = C(Gender)+C(Weight=106)+C(Weight=114)+..`. I guess a possible reason is that there are too little number of different `Weight` to regard it as continuous variable by Python. Is there a way that we enforce `Weight` as numeric variable during  the OLS regression?

Comment: What is the type of your weight column? Whether it is treated as categorical depends more on the type of the data in the DataFrame than the content of the data. For example numbers could be stored also in a column with an object dtype, which wouldn't be numeric.

Comment: I would not do what you are doing. You are admixing dimensions in your predictions and response which is physical nonsense. Take logarithms of everything and regress those for starters.

Comment: Thank you, guys. As feedback, I know the reason and would be happy to share with you how to fix. Note in the data, there are '.' on 2nd and 21th rows, so data is not clean. As long as removing the '.', the outcome will cope `weight` numeric. when reading the data, do `data = pandas.read_csv('brain_size.csv', sep=';', na_values='.')`.  Thank the author of the blog `Statistics in Python` providing the solution.

Comment: @Tim This is about data analysis, which is relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not do what you are doing. You are admixing dimensions in your predictions and response which is physical nonsense. For example, you may be able to correlate height and weight to something but height is L$^1$ and weight is (actually mass) density*L$^3$ and when you do this linearly your answers will be poorly correlated and heuristic to the point of tears. Take logarithms of everything and regress those to adjust for dimensionality. For gender code Male=1, Female=2. [Download this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6707938_An_improved_method_for_determining_renal_sufficiency_using_volume_of_distribution_and_weight_from_bolus_Tc-99m-DTPA_two_blood_sample_paediatric_data) as an example of how to do this regression.

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps someone else will post comments or answers. Any, problems or other difficulties, post them here.

Answer (score 2):

Run `data.dtypes` to see the data types of your variables.  I suspect that `Weight` will show up as having `Object` dtype.  If so, you can convert it to a numeric data type with [pandas.to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).